# How to create a synchronized multimap with Guava in one line?

Tags: java, generics, guava

This works:

```
Multimap<String, String> m = HashMultimap.create();
```

Also this works:

```
Multimap<String, String> m = HashMultimap.create();
Multimap<String, String> n = Multimaps.synchronizedMultimap(m);
```

But why does this not work?

```
Multimap<String, String> n = Multimaps.synchronizedMultimap(HashMultimap.create());
```

I get an error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Multimap Object,Object to 
>    Multimap String,String

I tried to add the <> in many places but had no success. What do I do wrong?

I am still stuck with Java 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an explicit type hint for `create`:

```
Multimap<String, String> n = Multimaps.synchronizedMultimap(
    HashMultimap.<String, String>create());
```

Java 8 had some type inference changes, so it works fine there without the hint.

Answer (score 0):

It needs explicit types in Java 7

```
Multimap<String, String> n = Multimaps.synchronizedMultimap(
    HashMultimap.<String, String>create());
```

Java 8 introduced some improvements in generics types inference, so initial code works as is in Java 8

```
Multimap<String, String> n = Multimaps.synchronizedMultimap(HashMultimap.create());
```

Comment: This just duplicates  [Jorns answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48185357/452775).